# array allocation problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a singleton object is a card I already defined I want to change the value of this card currant...

```
@interface CartesManager : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *carteMan ; 
    NSInteger indexCarteCourante ;
    BOOL isEditable ;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *carteMan ; 
@property(nonatomic)        NSInteger indexCarteCourante ; 
@property(nonatomic)        BOOL isEditable ; 

+(CartesManager*)sharedInstance;
```

Object:

```
@interface Carte : NSObject {
    NSString *titre ; 
    NSString *commentaire ; 
    UIImage *image1 ; 
    UIImage *image2 ; 
    NSString *information ; 
} 
@property (nonatomic,retain )NSString *titre ; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *commentaire ; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image1 ; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image2 ; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *information ; 





-(void) edit:(id)sender 
{
    Carte *uneCarte = [[Carte alloc]init]; 
    uneCarte.titre = textField.text ; 
    uneCarte.commentaire = textView.text ; 
    uneCarte.image1 = imageView1.image ; 
    uneCarte.image2 = imageView2.image; 
    [[[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan]objectAtIndex:[[CartesManager sharedInstance]indexCarteCourante]]addObject:uneCarte]; //don't Work to allocate in my array in this carte 
}
```

Comment: [[[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan]objectAtIndex:[[CartesManager sharedInstance]indexCarteCourante]]addObject:uneCarte]; //don't Work to allocate in my array this current carte }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding an object instead of modifying an existing object in the array.  Try:

```
-(void) edit:(id)sender
{ 
  Carte *uneCarte = [[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan]objectAtIndex:[[CartesManager sharedInstance]indexCarteCourante]];
  uneCarte.titre = textField.text;
  uneCarte.commentaire = textView.text;
  uneCarte.image1 = imageView1.image;
  uneCarte.image2 = imageView2.image;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

actually if [[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan]objectAtIndex:[[CartesManager sharedInstance]indexCarteCourante]]; was a Carte*, then he tried to add a Carte* to another Carte*:

```
[[[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan]objectAtIndex:[[CartesManager sharedInstance]indexCarteCourante]]addObject:uneCarte];
```

being equivalent to

```
Carte *carte = [[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan]objectAtIndex:[[CartesManager sharedInstance]indexCarteCourante]]
[carte addObject: uneCarte]
```

to add a Carte* to the array:

```
[[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan] addObject:uneCarte];
```

and to avoid such problem in the future refactor the code, all of those [[[[ in one line make it hard to understand and easy to make an error.